# ionic cordova build android --prod

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

i got a new error with ionic when we create a build for production using command

```
ionic cordova build --prod
```

it always gives an error at the point of ngc started

```
Running app-scripts build: --prod

[15:00:23]  build prod started ... 
[15:00:23]  clean started ... 
[15:00:23]  clean finished in 36 ms 
[15:00:23]  copy started ... 
[15:00:23]  ngc started ... 
Error: Type DashboardPage in /Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ts
is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
/Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/app/app.module.ts and
DashboardPageModule in /Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts! 
Please consider moving DashboardPage in
/Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ts to a 
higher module that imports AppModule in
/Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/app/app.module.ts and 
DashboardPageModule in /Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts. 
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DashboardPage in
/Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.ts
then import that NgModule in AppModule in 
/Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/app/app.module.ts 
and DashboardPageModule in /Users/sunny/Desktop/Apps/IONIC/MintOld/src/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says you're importing your module 2 times, maybe you have done lazy loading pages and forgot to delete the import of your module from `app.module.ts`

So if you're using lazy loading modules, go to your `app.module.ts` and look for your imported `DashboardPage` in `Declarations` and/or `entryComponents` array, if they're there just delete the DashboardPage from them.

If you're not lazy loading you'll need to delete the `dashboard.module.ts` file.

You can't have the page module imported to a same level `@NgModule`, that's what you're doing wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too. I just solved it by closing all `ionic` tasks running in parallel and deleting the `www` folder from my project folder.

I then just ran

`ionic cordova build android`

and then

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

And it worked. I don't know how / why , but doing it like this I did not get that error

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you have declared the ***DashboardPage*** in two modules, If you are using `this.navCtrl.push("DashboardPage")`, then remove ***DashboardPage*** from app.module.ts file under declatrations, or if you are using `this.navCtrl.push(DashboardPage)`, then delete the dashboard-page-module file.